# jQuery image slider fade effect doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, slider

I've made a simple image slider that fades-in an image, fades it out and than another one fades-in, an infinite loop. But, this doesn't work right away. It only works after it made a full circle. Which means: all the 6 images have been seen. Then the loop starts again at image one and the fade-in effect works. Why?

This is the HTML:

```
<body onload="Slider();">

<div id="container">
    <div id="slider">   

        <img id="img1" src="photos/everything/slide1.jpg" border="0"/>
        <img id="img2" src="photos/everything/slide2.jpg" border="0"/>
        <img id="img3" src="photos/everything/slide3.jpg" border="0"/>
        <img id="img4" src="photos/everything/slide4.jpg" border="0"/>
        <img id="img5" src="photos/everything/slide5.jpg" border="0"/>
        <img id="img6" src="photos/everything/slide6.jpg" border="0"/>

    </div>
</div>

</body>
```

And this is the javascript:

```
function Slider() {
    $("#slider #img1").show("fade", 500);
    $("#slider #img1").delay(5500).hide("fade", 500);

    var sc=$("#slider img").size();
    var count=2;

    setInterval(function(){
        $("#slider #img"+count).show("fade",500);
        $("#slider #img"+count).delay(5500).hide("fade", 500);

        if(count==sc){
            count=1;
        }else{
            count = count + 1;  
        }
    },6500);
}
```

And the CSS used for this page:

```
#slider{
    height: 600px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-top: 10px;
}

#slider img{
    height: 100%;
    max-width: none;
    display: block;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin: 0 auto; 
}
```

Comment: What isn't working? What does "after images" mean?

Comment: Well, it's a loop of 6 images that fade in and out. And what happens is that in the first cycle of images the fade in doesn't work. But after that cycle, the fade in starts to work.

Comment: So the fade effect is what's not working? Please clarify in your question.

Comment: Try [**this JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/FgMWQ/).

Comment: The jsfiddle does exactly the same.

Comment: So you are saying the images cycle through without a fade. Then once the first cycle is over the images then start to fade for you?  What browser and browser version are you using?

Comment: I tried it in (as far as I know) the latest versions of chrome, firefox and safari. And you are correct about the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fading effect is not working at first because all of your images are visible, and then you fade them out.

To avoid that, use `display:none;` in your css.

Then you can create a function `nextSlide()` that will call itself every *XX* milliseconds.

For example:

```
var sc=$("#slider img").size();
// Set count to 0 so that it goes to 1 on first call
var count=0;
// Call it for the first time
nextSlide();

function nextSlide(){
    // Go forward or back to the beginning?
    count=count==sc?1:++count;
    // FadeIn, wait, fadeOut
    $("#slider #img"+count).fadeIn(500).delay(1500).fadeOut(500);
    // Do the same thing in 2500 milliseconds
    setTimeout(nextSlide,2500);
}
```

### JS Fiddle Demo